# Error con Haml-rails: no se encuentra el fichero o directorio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Me acontece que me da este error a la hora de aplicar este comando con Rails 5

```
rails generate haml:application_layout convert
```

No me convierte nada y me sale esto en la consola

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Repos\
>     Use --trace for backtrace.

Uso Windows 10. ¿Qué posibles soluciones habrá?

me sale lo mismo al poner

rails generate haml:application_layout convert --trace

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta el error completo que te sale con `rails generate haml:application_layout convert --trace`?

Comment: Me sale lo mismo                                                             Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Repos\
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Success! app/views/layouts/application.html.haml is created.
Please remove the erb file: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: Pero en lo que pusiste en tu comentario dice que agregues `--trace` para ver el backtrace, no lo has agregado como te indiqué en el primer comentario, eso permite mostrar el error completo de donde se está generando. Y no agregues el mensaje de error completo como un comentario, edita tu pregunta, que es mucho más legible ahí.